# Java-SWT: How to update Label?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, label, project

I'm new at Java SWT. I created the game"2048" ( by MVP model), and I try to update the Score label in the Gui - I don't know why but the score doesn't updated. I'm not sure how to use all the Listners and which one will be good for this action, can you help me?

```
public void buttons() {
    Group group = new Group(this.shell, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
    final Label label2 = new Label(group, SWT.BORDER);
    Button UndoMove = new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
    Button RestartGame = new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
    Button LoadGame = new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
    Button SaveGame = new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);

    group.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    **int i = board.getScore();
    label2.setText("Your Score is: " + i);

    label2.update();**

    public class GameBoard extends Canvas {

        protected int N;
        protected Tile[][] tile;
        int[][] boardData;
        protected int Score = 0;
        protected int MaxScore = 0;

        public GameBoard(Composite arg0, int arg1, int n) {
            super(arg0, arg1);

            N = n;
            boardData = new int[N][N];
            setLayout(new GridLayout(N, true));
            tile = new Tile[N][N];

        }

        public void initilizeValueInTile() {

            if (boardData != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

                        if (tile[i][j] == null) {
                            tile[i][j] = new Tile(this, SWT.BORDER);
                            tile[i][j].setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

                        }
                        tile[i][j].setValue(boardData[i][j]);

                    }
            }
        }


        public void setBoard(int[][] data) {
            boardData = data;
            initilizeValueInTile();

        }

        **

        public void SetScore(int s) {
            Score = s;

        }

        public int getScore() {
            return Score;**
        }


        public class GameView extends Observable implements View

        @Override
        public void displayScore(int score) {
            System.out.println(score);
            board.SetScore(score);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the label you just need to call `label.setText`, as you do. If you want to do it when the score is changed, the simplest approach is just to call `label.setText` in `displayScore` or in `SetScore` (the normal Java name would be `setScore`). This doesn't fit into MVP pattern, but I don't see it in your code anyway.